# What's wrong with my delegate?

Tags: swift, delegates

I am new to swift and right now I am learning delegate. I think I already do the right things but it is still not working.

What I am doing was passing data from my `ViewController` to `TestViewController`

**ViewController:**

```
protocol viewControllerDelegate: class {
  func viewcontrollerdelegate(setviewcontrollerdelegate: ViewController)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITextFieldDelegate {
  weak var delegate: viewControllerDelegate?

  @IBAction func nextViewandDelegate(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.delegate?.viewcontrollerdelegate(self)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showTestSegue" {
      if let testViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? TestViewController {
        testViewController.address = address.text!
        testViewController.phone = phone.text!
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**TestViewController:**

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

  var name: String?
  var address: String?
  var phone: String?
  var trydelegate: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewcontroller") as! ViewController
    VC.delegate = self
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    addressLabel.text = address!
    phoneLabel.text = phone!
    trydelegateLabel.text = trydelegate //always nil here
  }
}

extension TestViewController:viewControllerDelegate {
  func viewcontrollerdelegate(setviewcontrollerdelegate: ViewController) {
    self.trydelegate = setviewcontrollerdelegate.address.text!
  }
}
```

I used segue to pass address and phone and they worked well.

But I am suck with delegate. Can anyone help me a little bit with it? I know the question is a little easy for you here.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TestViewController` in `viewDidLoad` you create new object `vc` which is not he same as the one which call `prepareForSegue` so that's why it doesn't work.

To fix this remove the code from `viewDidLoad`:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewcontroller") as! ViewController
vc.delegate = self
```

And in `prepareForSegue` add one line:

```
testViewController.phone = phone.text!
// New line
self.delegate = testViewController
```

That should help.

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'TestViewController.Type' to type 'viewControllerDelegate?'  I tried and this was What I got

Comment: Are you sure you have self.delegate = testViewController? not TestViewController? I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: sorry about that.It was my fault. I have already try self.delegate = testViewController many times. But I still didn't get the value...:(

Comment: You don't get the value because the logic you have is wrong here. You have your view controller with IBAction which triggers delegate method. In prepareForSegue you set up the delegate. And it load new view of type TestViewController. How do you call your IBAction nextViewandDelegate from testVC? You cannot call it from testVC so it want call viewcontrollerdelegate method.

Comment: Brother,you are right!I just notice that and I fixed it.I have already post my answer.Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showTestSegue" {
        if let testViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? TestViewController {

            testViewController.address = address.text!
            testViewController.phone = phone.text!
            self.delegate = testViewController
            self.delegate?.viewcontrollerdelegate(self)
        }
    }
}
```

remove @IBAction func nextViewandDelegate(sender: AnyObject) and change that prepareforsegue

I fixed it......it is working right now but I dont know why